# 1С-Битрикс, его блог и комментарии

Tags: битрикс

Есть интернет-магазин на Bitrix, есть в нем комментарии табового вида со вкладками vk, fb и обычные. Они есть в категории товара, но их нет в блоговой категории, то есть в новостях. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как их туда закинуть? Я сначала подумала, что раз уже все есть, то можно просто вывести их и поковырялась в шаблоне страницы, но черт подери сейчас все табы слетели, руководство тонновое просто. Буду очень благодарна, если кто-то подскажет по каким запросам вообще можно найти ответ, ибо Яндекс ответами особо не балует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю вам нужно [это](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/service/forum/components_2/forum_topic_reviews.php).

> В визуальном редакторе компонент находится в Компоненты > Общение > Форум.

Однако все-таки не советую править код из визуального редактора.